# When an Ajax return sets some var to 0, I need to stop all subsequent requests, how within a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin, that fires off for each pagination click on a page. Mind you, that this pagination is front loaded with all of its data. The plugin that I have fires off to retrieve additional information pages on the current paginated view. So, each click instantiates a new plugin - but the same as before (namespace), so it overrides the previous dataSets that set etc..

Anyways, there might be a point where the .ajax url I am hitting is turned off so that the return will hand something like data.isOff = 1 or data.isOff = 0 , etc.. so that I know that the service is suppressed.

Is there a way for any to persist a value from one instantiation to the next of a plugin and if that value is false, then don't instantiate the new plugin call.. ie.. don't hit the init function. just fail out.

I, of course, can set a global var and to it that way, but curious if there is a way I can do it within the plugin so as to not have any outside vars existing.

I tried to put it in my init function, and set it in my options.. just seems that when I try to instantiate a new plugin, all bets from the previous data is gone.

Comment: what is the crux of the issue? how to get server to tell js code not to send more requests? What datatype is being returned?

Comment: Yeah, that is the jist. I can retrieve the flag just fine. And of course, I can assign that value to the options vars etc.. but I need that value to persist Even when I make a subsequent plugin call so it shortcircuits it and makes it not instantiate. Basically, I call the plugin at least once.. if the controller (backend data retrieval code) is enabled, I get a flag that says, once it is returned.. data.isOff = false..  great. I keep calling my plugin with new data and processing etc.. but if its set to true. I need to not enable the plugin anymore as the ajax call is not returning anything.

Comment: ..continue - I just don't want to keep making ajax calls. No reason to keep pinging the server for data that I know is not gonna return anything (since the first request sent back a : data.isOff = true).

Comment: can't see any of plugin code so simplest path is global variable. Another path is set flag in data attribute of an element using `data()` method.

Comment: yeah - I am using the data() method for some other things but since this plugin is used on various places, it would be more code to do that.. I think global var is best then. Thanks for your time to answer my inquires.

Comment: question and details are really a lot more abstract than they should be to expect any more definitive solutions